# How to compare agreement of two methods with gold standard?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, agreement-statistics

Let's assume that there are two medical students who both guess the age of several patients. If the actual age of the patients is the gold standard, I can assess the agreement of each student with the gold standard using tests like ICC or Bland-Altman plots / limits of agreement.

What would be the best approach if I want to assess who of the students is better at guessing the age of patients, i.e., who guesses closer to the gold standard? My first intuition would be to calculate the difference from the gold standard for each student and compare those differences, so if S1 and S2 are the students' guesses and P is the gold standard, calculate (S1 - P) and (S2 - P) and compare those values using a Wilcoxon signed-rank test. Is this appropriate or should I do something else?

Comment: The triviality of the age-guessing game indicates it is a metaphor for an assessment of greater consequence.  This raises the question of what "better" ought to mean.  To continue the metaphor, suppose student A guesses the age exactly for most people, but mistakes octogenarians for children--a huge error; and suppose student B is always incorrect, but never by more than two years.  Who is to say which is better? Your readers cannot, because we do not know the real application. It would therefore behoove you to disclose information about the consequences of guesses being incorrect.

Comment: Another issue to keep in mind is that mistaking a 12-year-old for a 2-year old is more of a mistake than mistaking a 92-year-old for an 82-year-old. The true age will affect how severe of a mistake a miss is, even though both mistakes are missing old by ten years. Also, missing old (50, guess 51) and missing young 51, guess 50) may not be the same.